# /dev/fd inconsistency

Tags: shell, file-descriptors, streams

What explains the following inconsistency in the reported contents of `/dev/fd`?

```
erhannis@mnode6:/dev/fd$ ll /dev/fd/
total 0
dr-x------ 2 erhannis erhannis  0 Jan 12 22:10 .
dr-xr-xr-x 9 erhannis erhannis  0 Jan 12 22:10 ..
lrwx------ 1 erhannis erhannis 64 Jan 12 22:10 0 -> /dev/pts/8
lrwx------ 1 erhannis erhannis 64 Jan 12 22:10 1 -> /dev/pts/8
lrwx------ 1 erhannis erhannis 64 Jan 12 22:10 2 -> /dev/pts/8
lr-x------ 1 erhannis erhannis 64 Jan 12 22:10 3 -> /proc/24334/fd
erhannis@mnode6:/dev/fd$ ll
total 0
dr-x------ 2 erhannis erhannis  0 Jan 12 21:42 .
dr-xr-xr-x 9 erhannis erhannis  0 Jan 12 21:42 ..
lrwx------ 1 erhannis erhannis 64 Jan 12 21:42 0 -> /dev/pts/8
lrwx------ 1 erhannis erhannis 64 Jan 12 21:42 1 -> /dev/pts/8
lrwx------ 1 erhannis erhannis 64 Jan 12 21:42 2 -> /dev/pts/8
lrwx------ 1 erhannis erhannis 64 Jan 12 21:55 255 -> /dev/pts/8
```

Specifically, note that `ll` alone shows a file `255` linked to `/dev/pts/8`, but `ll /dev/fd/` shows instead a file `3` linked to `/proc/24334/fd`.  (The proc number changes each time; I suspect it to be the process number of `ll` itself.)

...I also note, now, that the dates are different - am I getting a different directory for `.` than for `/dev/fd/`?  I further note that I can't create a file in /dev/fd (with either path).

Comment: I think this is a bash-ism. What’s your shell?

Comment: @RichHomolka Yeah, bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, `ls` list the contents the `/dev/fd -> /proc/self/fd -> /proc/<pid_of_ls>/fd`, and in the second case, that of `/proc/<pid_of_the_shell>/fd`.

While `/dev/fd` is a (magical) symbolic link to `/proc/self/fd`, `.` (the current directory, as listed by `ls` when called without arguments) isn't, and it was already resolved to `/proc/<pid_of_the_shell>/fd` when you called `cd /dev/fd` before.

> `ll` alone shows a file `255` linked to `/dev/pts/8`

That's a file descriptor used internally by the bash shell, and which being opened with the `O_CLOEXEC` flag, is automatically closed when the `execve(2)` system call is used to execute another program (like `/bin/ls` in your case).

> I further note that I can't create a file in /dev/fd (with either path).

Creating files is not possible in the `procfs` filesystem on Linux.

You can however mount another filesystem over any directory under `/proc` -- or bind mount any file or directory over any path under `/proc`. Just like anywhere else.

Comment: Ohhh, interesting.  That makes sense, I think.  Thanks